# How to save call_user_func_array() function output

Tags: php, function

i am trying to make a static site generator which works with a great routing class.

```php
if (php_sapi_name() === "cli") {
    foreach ($router->get() as $route) {
        $out = ob_get_contents();
        call_user_func_array($route['function'], array());
        ob_end_clean();
        file_put_contents("./temp/" . $route['expression'] . ".html", $out);
    }
}
```

So i am trying this I can see the compiled html code through terminal but file is empty.
How can I save output of call_user_func_array() function?

Comment: You need to call `ob_get_contents()` *after* you call the function, not before it.

Comment: You can also combine `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()` with `ob_get_clean()`

Comment: I will try now. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I can still see the output from terminal not in the files.

Comment: Still the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example:

```
if (php_sapi_name() === "cli") {
    // Start output buffering here
    ob_start();
    foreach ($router->get() as $route) {
        call_user_func_array($route['function'], array());
        // get output of `$route['function']` to $out variable
        $out = ob_get_contents();
        // clean buffer
        ob_clean();

        file_put_contents("./temp/" . $route['expression'] . ".html", $out);
    }
    // stop output buffering
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to clean the output buffer between iterations? Otherwise each file will include the contents of the previous files.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, will fix in a minute.

Comment: Sure. I will try.